# Enable other community Helm Charts in the ICP Catalog?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

After installing IBM Cloud Private on laptop using the Vagrant setup, I've been trying to add a Jenkins instance to my private cloud.

The directions [here](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/running-jenkins-cicd-deployments-in-an-ibm-cloud-private-environment/) are for an older version of ICP and no longer apply.

I've tried to add both the [Jenkins Helm Chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) and the [Kubernetes Charts](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts) as new `Admin > Repositories` but the charts don't show up in the `Catalog`.

What needs to be done to make other repo's charts available in the Catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to deploy jenkins, you can try to add repository as follow.
Name: stable
Url: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

Click sync after you add and you should be able to see the stable charts in the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Sync Repositories from Admin > Repositories?
When you run that, you should view the logs (in another tab perhaps) for the `helm-api` pod and see if you find any reference to your new repositories being indicated.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the logs don't have sufficient scrollback to see the beginning of them.... I get a `404` from the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/charts/master/repo/stable` URL and the `Add repository` button removes the trailing `/`.